# Declarative schema uses padding in 2.3, gone in 2.4, do we have to use it?

Tags: magento2.3, database, magento2.4, declarative-schema

In a module we're developing we declare a new database table with a foreign key relationship to the `sales_order` table. We want to support Magento 2.3 and 2.4, so we use the declarative schema (`db_schema.xml`).

The schema looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="my_order_table" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="int" unsigned="true" nullable="false" name="sales_order_id" padding="10" />
        <!-- extra columns, including a PK -->
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="MY_ORDER_SALES_ORDER_ID" table="my_order_table" column="sales_order_id" referenceTable="sales_order" referenceColumn="entity_id" />
    </table>
</schema>
```

So the column `my_order_table.sales_order_id` references Magento's `sales_order.entity_id`, and all is well. As long as we use Magento 2.4, because for 2.3 their own declaration is different. Compare:

[Magento 2.3](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/db_schema.xml):

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Flat Order">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true"
                comment="Entity ID"/>
```

[Magento 2.4](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/db_schema.xml#L11):

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Flat Order">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true"
                comment="Entity ID"/>
```

In 2.3, there's the `padding="10"` attribute on the column, which is gone in 2.4. If we add that same attribute to our schema, it works in both 2.3 (on MariaDB 10.3) and 2.4 (on MySQL 5.7). If we omit that padding, it works in 2.4 but in 2.3 gives the error while running `setup:upgrade`:

> Column definition "sales_order_id" and reference column definition "entity_id" are different in tables "my_order_table" and "sales_order"

This attribute was [removed in a commit named "MC-14884: MySQL-8 and MariaDB-10.4 support"](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/159b377cd29be55c8d3af75f0cd5ba731a21b3c3).

So my question is: why does it work if *we* declare the referencing column with padding, and what problems can that cause on later upgrades? Is it related to MariaDB?

Comment: Very good question! I have exactly the same question just now :) Can you answer it yourself in the meantime?